# How can I read the analytics of triggered goals?

Tags: xdb, reporting

I am trying to trigger a goal from the client side following the below link
https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2016/02/integrating-addthis-with-sitecore-goals.html

Now I would like to generate a monthly report for this specific goal's analytics. Can you guide me towards different options?

Using Sitecore version 8.1 with MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-conversions-tab-reports.html#UUID-830dcc82-f326-b8af-3d36-38dc92c63719_id__Goals

In the `Experience Analytics`, in the `Conversions` tab, you can get the goals reports. Not sure what is exactly possible in 8.1 (the link above is for the 8.1 specific docs, so the report is there), but in a 9 version I can easily filter on the goal and the timeframe and see all analytics.

If this ootb information is not sufficient, you'll need to create a custom report but I would start with checking the ootb information.

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-experience-analytics-report.html

Comment: Can you please point me to the custom reports tutorial on xDB ?

Comment: Added link in the answer

Comment: I am sorry ,I overlooked it .Thanks